# ¿Cual es la Mejor Función para Convertir Imágenes a Color?

Tags: vb.net

Mi Pregunta es la Siguiente: ¿Alguien sabe como Devolver-le el color a una imagen en blancos y negros? 
Tengo el Siguiente código que lo hace pero aun no es perfecto y quisiera que lo fuera, no se si lo estoy haciendo bien del todo pero esto le da 4 colores de los 6 de las escala HSL...

```html
Public Sub RestoreByRGB(ByVal Imagen As PictureBox)
        On Error Resume Next

        Imagen1.Image = Imagen.Image.Clone
        Texto.Text = "Preparando para Restauracion de Color a toda la Imagen... Preparing To Restore Color All Image..." & vbCrLf &
                     "ALT+F4 para Acelerar Conversion ALT+F4 Accelerate conversion"

        Dim imAgtEmp1 As New Bitmap(Imagen.Image)
        Dim imAgtEmp2 As New Bitmap(Imagen.Image)
        Dim ElGrIs As Integer = 0
        Dim ElRojo As Integer = 0
        Dim ElVerde As Integer = 0
        Dim ElAzul As Integer = 0
        Largo = imAgtEmp1.Width
        Alto = imAgtEmp1.Height

        For i = 0 To Alto - 1
            For j = 0 To Largo - 1
                ElColor = imAgtEmp1.GetPixel(j, i)

                ' Colorizamos de Nuevo El Pixel Ampliandolo 3 Veces en Escala
                Dim N As Integer = 0
                For N = 0 To 2
                    ElRojo = ((((CInt(ElColor.R.ToString) + 1) / 0.72))) - 1
                    ElVerde = ((((CInt(ElColor.G.ToString) + 1) / 0.256)) / 3) - 1
                    ElAzul = ((((CInt(ElColor.B.ToString) + 1) / 0.2816)) / 3) - 1

                    If N = 2 Then
                        ElRojo = ElRojo - 200
                        ElVerde = ElVerde - 200
                        ElAzul = ElAzul - 200
                    End If

                    If ElRojo < 0 Then ElRojo = 0
                    If ElVerde < 0 Then ElVerde = 0
                    If ElAzul < 0 Then ElAzul = 0
                    If ElRojo > 255 Then ElRojo = 255
                    If ElVerde > 255 Then ElVerde = 255
                    If ElAzul > 255 Then ElAzul = 255
                    ElColor = Color.FromArgb(CInt(ElRojo), CInt(ElVerde), CInt(ElAzul))
                Next

                ElRojo = ElRojo + 64
                ElVerde = ElVerde + 64
                ElAzul = ElAzul + 64

                If ElRojo < 0 Then ElRojo = 0
                If ElVerde < 0 Then ElVerde = 0
                If ElAzul < 0 Then ElAzul = 0
                If ElRojo > 255 Then ElRojo = 255
                If ElVerde > 255 Then ElVerde = 255
                If ElAzul > 255 Then ElAzul = 255

                ElColor = Color.FromArgb(CInt(ElRojo), CInt(ElVerde), CInt(ElAzul))

                ' Por último seteamos el color nuevo
                imAgtEmp2.SetPixel(j, i, ElColor)
            Next
        Next
        Imagen.Image = imAgtEmp2.Clone
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pude hacer-lo mejor así:

```html
Public Sub ConvertGrayscaleByRGBREAL(ByVal Imagen As PictureBox)
        ' Este procedimiento obtiene la imagen a escala de grises
        ' de una imagen contenida en la caja de imagen
        ' la explicación es muy similar al negativo lo único que cambia es la fórmula
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim grayscale As New Imaging.ColorMatrix(New Single()() _
        { _
           New Single() {0.0457, 0.0457, 0.0457, 0, 0}, _
            New Single() {0.6074, 0.6074, 0.6074, 0, 0}, _
            New Single() {0.3469, 0.3469, 0.3469, 0, 0}, _
            New Single() {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, _
            New Single() {0, 0, 0, 0, 1} _
        })
        Dim bmp As New Bitmap(Imagen.Image)
        Dim imgattr As New Imaging.ImageAttributes()
        imgattr.SetColorMatrix(grayscale)
        Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
            g.DrawImage(bmp, New Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), _
                        0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height, _
                        GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imgattr)
        End Using
        Imagen.Image = bmp

    End Sub
```